# Uncaught typeerror: Object #<object> has no method 'method'

Tags: javascript, object, methods, set, typeerror

So here's the object 'playerTurnObj'

```
function playerTurnObj(set_turn) {
    this.playerTurn=set_turn;
    function setTurn(turnToSet) {
        this.playerTurn=turnToSet;
    }
    function getTurn() {
        return this.playerTurn;
    }
}
```

and here is what I'm doing with it

```
var turn = new playerTurnObj();
turn.setTurn(1);
```

so I try to make the script do the setTurn() method in playerTurnObj() to save a 'turn' in a game I'm making. The problem is, it does not do the turn.setTurn(1); part because I keep getting the error above

what am I doing wrong? I searched, but I could not find an exact answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way JavaScript works. Your "constructor" function contains inline functions that are not visible outside of the scope of `playerTurnObj`. So your variable `turn` does not have a method `setTurn` defined, as the error message states correctly. Probably you want something like this:

```
function playerTurnObj(set_turn) {
    this.playerTurn=set_turn;
}

playerTurnObj.prototype = {
    setTurn: function(turnToSet) {
        this.playerTurn=turnToSet;
    },
    getTurn: function() {
        return this.playerTurn;
    }
};
```

Now your variable `turn` has two methods `setTurn` and `getTurn` that operate on the instance you created with `new`.

Comment: The other suggestions here do work too, there are many ways to achieve  this. Usind prototype has the advantage of not filling up memory with each instance.

Answer (score 1):

The `setTurn` and `getTurn` functions are private so they return `undefined` rather than invoking the function.  You can do:

```
function playerTurnObj(set_turn) {
    this.playerTurn=set_turn;
    this.setTurn = setTurn;
    this.getTurn = getTurn;

    function setTurn(turnToSet) {
        this.playerTurn=turnToSet;
    }
    function getTurn() {
        return this.playerTurn;
    }
}
```

You then have `public` `setTurn` and `getTurn` methods and can invoke them as follows:

```
var turn = new playerTurnObj();
turn.setTurn(1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ht688/

Answer (score 0):

What I make out of it is you need to return the object this in function playerTurnObj(). So your new code will look something like:

```
function playerTurnObj(set_turn) {
    this.playerTurn=set_turn;
    function setTurn(turnToSet) {
        this.playerTurn=turnToSet;
    }
    function getTurn() {
        return this.playerTurn;
    }
    return this;
}
```