# uncaught typeError: object [object] has no method 'wallpaper'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been attempting to play around with this plugin from Ben Plum over on Formstone.it.
Even though this piece:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".wallpapered").wallpaper();
            });
</script>
```

Is straight from their demo, I'm getting this error.

StackOverflow suggested this:
[Uncaught typeerror: Object #<object> has no method 'method'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623973/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-method)

But have not been able to figure it out. Help?

Comment: Are jQuery and the wallpaper library loaded properly?

Comment: Probably not. I'm pretty new to jQuery.

Comment: Would you give us your HTML, or at least the part where you load the JavaScript files?  Have you loaded jQuery before Wallpaper?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: <link href="demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
<script src="http://formstone.it/js/demo.js"></script>
<link href="../jquery.fs.wallpaper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="../jquery.fs.wallpaper.js"></script>
<style>
.wallpapered {background: #eee; margin: 0 0 20px; padding-top: 50%; width: 100%;}
.wallpapered.square {padding-top: 100%;}
.wallpapered.bar {margin: -25px 0;}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".wallpapered").wallpaper();
});
</script>

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you were asking? I hope it is

Answer (score 0):

What does your file structure look like? The demo uses paths relative to the demo's directory structure which may differ from your site's.

If your site's directory structure is something like:

```
├─ index.html
├─ css
|  └── jquery.wallpaper.js
├─ js
|  ├── jquery.js
|  └── jquery.wallpaper.js
```

Then you will need to include the file relative to the index.html file:

```
<link href="css/jquery.fs.wallpaper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fs.wallpaper.js"></script>
```

Or use absolute paths:

```
<link href="//example.com/css/jquery.fs.wallpaper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="//example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//example.com/js/jquery.fs.wallpaper.js"></script>
```